# Hibernate Exceptions: ClassCastException and QueryException

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception

What I want is a that a customer can get to his profilepage. The anchor he needs to click is as followed:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/profile/${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}"></a>
```

And I have the following method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editProfileIdPage(@PathVariable("username") String username) {

        ModelAndView customerEditView = new ModelAndView("/customer/customerHome");
        customerEditView.addObject("customer", customerService.getCustomerByUserName(username));
        customerEditView.addObject("title", "Welkom");

        return customerEditView;
    }
```

And next I have a User model and a Customer model. I left out all the constructors and a some of the getters and setters to minimize the code.

USER MODEL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "...")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

        private String username;
        private boolean enabled;
        private String password;
        private Set<Storeproperties> storepropertieses = new HashSet<Storeproperties>(
                0);
        private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
        private Set<Customerproperties> customerpropertieses = new HashSet<Customerproperties>(
                0);

        @Id
        @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
        public String getUsername() {
            return this.username;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
        public Set<Customerproperties> getCustomerpropertieses() {
            return this.customerpropertieses;
        }

    }
```

CUSTOMER MODEL:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customerproperties", catalog = "...")
public class Customerproperties implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int customerid;
    private User user;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String phonenumber;
    private String zipcode;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customerid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getCustomerid() {
        return customerid;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_username", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

}
```

And finally the method I use in my DAO to obtain the customerproperties is as follows:

```
public Customerproperties getCustomerByUserName(String username) {
        Customerproperties customer = (Customerproperties) getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Customerproperties c inner join c.User u where u.username = :user")
                .setParameter("user", username)
                .uniqueResult();
        return customer;
    }
```

When I click on the link i get the following exception:

```
 "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: User of: com.IS202_1.users.model.Customerproperties [from com.IS202_1.users.model.Customerproperties c inner join c.User u where u.username = :user]"
```

And when i change the c.User to c.user i get the following exception:

```
 "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.IS202_1.users.model.Customerproperties"
```

Comment: For better reading, I would suggest changing .setParameter("user", username) to .setParameter("username", username)

Comment: You show us very extensive code.  Try to summarize the code to a minimal reproductible case (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Christophe alright I'll try!